# get value from swift dictionary

Tags: swift

```
 let dict1 : [String:Any] = ["id":19,"userinfo": ["name":"janak",
                                                  "mobileN":999889,
                                                  "email": "jana4@gmail.com"]]
```

how i gat email value from user info ?
my code is

```
let  cvc  = dict1["userinfo"]
print(cvc!)
```

Comment: `print(cvc!)` works right? `cvc` is `[String: Any]`. So do `let cvc = dict1["userinfo"] as! [Strnig: Any]`, and `let email = cvc["email"] as! String`.

Comment: I rollbacked your edits for two reasons, you completely trashed the formatting I had already fixed for you and most importantly, don't add an extra question when people have already answered your original one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell the compiler what type you expect to get when you query `userinfo`. Since the expectation can fail, you then also need to unwrap the optional (the `?` in my example) and what you expect to get when reading `email`:

```
let email: String? = (dict1["userinfo"] as? [String:Any])?["email"] as? String
```

Comment: correct.........

Answer (score 0):

you need to typecast key to a particular type, since user info is again dictionary,we need to typecast it .

```
if let userInfoData = dict1["userinfo"] as? [String: Any], let email = userInfoData["email"] as? String {
print("Email: \(email)") }
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use optional chaining to access the email value:

```
if let email = (dict1["userinfo"] as? [String:Any])?["email"] as? String {
  print(email)     
}
```